# Improper app resolution on emulator

Tags: android, screen, emulation

An app I am creating in Android Studio is spanning about 350dp by width and 390dp by height. When running the app on Nexus 5 emulator, part of the app UI is cut out. The emulator only displays about 200dp of the app's width; meaning that part of it is cut out.

The emulator does not show the whole GUI and at the same time, its packing part of GUI horizontally instead of spacing them accordingly as I created it. Also the the theme background is not also displayed as I chose fro the theme combobox rather it displays the default theme of a blue at upper title bar.

Comment: Please do not assume that the whole of your readership are "gentlemen"; developers of all genders use this site.

Answer (score 0):

setting specified height and width will cause different phone screens to display differently. I would recomend as you are using android studio to use relative or linier layouts in your activity layout xml insted of setting specified display height and width.

Comment: Sorry, am using relative layout already. the height and width i stated above was just a guess measurement using the ruler margins of the AS. the initial settings was match_parent for  both height and width. I want to know please, does expanding the layout with the arrow that is downwards in the design editor making it larger than the default size, could this be the cause of the app not displaying all its contents on the emulator.